# eclipse plugin: dynamic menu synchronization

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, menuitem

i am building an eclipse plugin and trying to build a dynamic menu which will display as menu itens the exceptions a class throws(i read these data from a .txt file).

Problem is: sometimes the menu itens are not drawed. Sometimes the menu is created,but the submenus don´t. And even more strange is this: When i minimize and maximize my eclipse, my submenu itens appear! What is going on here? I tried putting my "public void fill(Menu menu, int index)" method that is located on the class that extends ContributionItem, but that didn´t work.

Please help. This eclipse is going crazy ;_;

Comment: We need to see the code creating the menu to have any chance of helping.